# Display value of cell adjacent from another cell

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to display the maximum demand and the month associated with that demand. The month column is column A and the demand is column E. I'm pretty sure my issue lies in how I'm addressing MonthOf_Demand but can't seem to figure this out my self. Any hints/tips/methods are extremely appreciated!

The issue I'm having is that I have column titles in the 1st cell above my data, and when I run the code it's returning both the incorrect date and demand associated with it. This is my spreadsheet so far:

[image]

It is displaying values but they are incorrect so that's a start.

This is my coding so far (thanks to the help of other great people on this site!):

```
Sub MonthHighestDemand()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Max_Demand As Long
Dim RowOf_Demand As Long
Dim MonthOf_Demand As Date

Set ws = Sheets("DATA")

Max_Demand = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Columns("E"))
RowOf_Demand = WorksheetFunction.Match(Max_Demand, ws.Columns("E"), 1)
MonthOf_Demand = WorksheetFunction.Index(ws.Columns("A"), RowOf_Demand)

MsgBox "The maximum demand is " & Max_Demand & " which occurs at " & MonthOf_Demand

End Sub
```

Comment: The third parameter of `MATCH` is supposed to be `0` for an exact match, so thats a start. But I think I would use `Range.Find`  instead of your last two worksheetfunctions.

Comment: You need to dimension `Max_Demand` as `Double`  to get the correct value.        
FYI - If you have duplicates of the `Max` value and use `1` in the 3rd parameter of `Match` and you will select the last value in the column, but if you use `0` you will select the first value in the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a couple minor tweaks to your function parameters:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MonthHighestDemand()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")

    Dim maxDemand As Variant
    Dim maxRow As Long
    Dim maxMonth As Long
    maxDemand = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Columns("E"))
    maxRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(maxDemand, ws.Columns("E"), 0)
    maxMonth = Month(WorksheetFunction.Index(ws.Columns("A"), maxRow))
    Debug.Print "max month is " & maxMonth
End Sub
```